# Ruby fcgi with spawn-fcgi closes when a page is requested

Tags: ruby, nginx, fastcgi

I have a Ruby script called server.rb that I open using `spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9001 /bin/ruby server.rb`.

Running `sudo netstat -lnptu | grep :9001` tells me that `ruby` is listening.

I have also set nginx up to pass .rb files to 127.0.0.1:9001

But once I request a .rb file:

1. `ruby` dissapears from `netstat`
2. nginx returns a 502 error (bad gateway)
3. This gets printed to the console: `2015/06/02 14:47:37 [error] 1852#0: *30 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /ruby/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/"`

server.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "fcgi"

loop FCGI.each do |request|
    File.write("test.txt", "Loading file #{__FILE__}!") 
    request.out.print "Content-Type: text/plain\\n\\nHello from #{__FILE__}"
    request.finish
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in:

```
\\n\\n
```

you are escaping the backslash and effectively don't have a newline in the output. what happens is that the client receives the whole line and treats it as header and after that closes the connection

Replace with:

```
request.out.print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\nHello from #{__FILE__}"
```